# Jax-rs rest api in java ee on wildfly does not work

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, wildfly, java-ee-8

I have rest api wrote in java ee and deployed in wildfly 20.0.0.
I read all the Documentation on jax-rs and rest apis tutorials but it does notwork.
When i build and deploy application and try to approach url of methods a I get only 404 in browser. In wildfly log is nothing new written. I started to think that problem could be with some missing configuration in wildfly but have not found a thing about it.

Here is my Application class

```
@ApplicationPath("/pato-api")
public class PatoApplication extends Application {


  public PatoApplication(@Context ServletConfig servletConfig) {
    super();
    BeanConfig beanConfig = new BeanConfig();
    beanConfig.setVersion("1.0");
    beanConfig.setSchemes(new String[]{"http"});
    beanConfig.setHost("localhost:8080");
    beanConfig.setBasePath("/pato-api");
    beanConfig.setResourcePackage("cz.upol.pato.ejb.autentification.rest");
    beanConfig.setScan(true);
  }

  @Override
  public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
    Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
    classes.add(UserResource.class);
    classes.add(UserDto.class);
    classes.add(io.swagger.jaxrs.listing.ApiListingResource.class);
    classes.add(io.swagger.jaxrs.listing.SwaggerSerializers.class);
    return classes;
  }

}
```

Here is rest service:

```
    @Path("/model/user")
    @Produces({ "application/json" })
    @Api(value = "/model/user")
    @Getter @Setter @NoArgsConstructor @AllArgsConstructor
    public class UserResource {


    @GET
    @Path("/userDto")
    public String getUser()  {
        return "Rest works";
    }
 }
```

And here is my pom.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>cz.pato</groupId>
    <artifactId>pato-ejb</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>ejb</packaging>

    <name>pato-ejb</name>

    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.test.skip>true</maven.test.skip> 
        <output.directory>${wildfly.deployments}</output.directory>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.9.Final</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ehcache</groupId>
            <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.12</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    
    

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <ejbVersion>3.1</ejbVersion>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>7.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <finalName>pato-ejb</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

Wilfly is running on default port 8080 and when Im testing it Im trying to access url: http://localhost:8080/pato-ejb/pato-api/model/user/userDto

Comment: Tha packaging in the pom should be war not ejb. I don't know how much of that make a difference. Also make sure the war is deployed correctly. Other than that, the code you've posted looks fine to me.

Comment: Thank you that was exactly it! ... I changed packaging to war, added war.xml and some jersey servlet dependencies to pom and it works.